# How can I handle the device sleeping in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to know when the device (ios or android) goes to sleep or wakes from sleep.

I've tried using the react-navigation-5 `focus` navigation feature which seems to only detect changes within the react environment (so not when the device is sleeping or when the app goes to the background)

I have also tried the `AppState` event listener to know when the app is active/inactive. This works to know when the app goes to the background or foreground, however, react doesn't seem to recognize the sleeping device as inactive so it never triggers the listener's event.